# can't find the syntax error in the code

Tags: python, syntax-error

this code is giving a syntax error when interpreted
I appreciate the help
this code is supposed to return the length of each mp3 file

```
    import os, sys
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

USAGE = "python %s <folder here>" %(sys.argv[0])

def get_file_length(path):
    #print "path is " + path
    audio = MP3(path)
    return int(audio.info.length)

def process_folder(folder):
    for item in os.listdir(folder):
        if os.path.isdir(folder+item):
            process_folder(folder+item+"/")
        else:
            if not item.startswith("."):
                path = folder+item
                length = get_file_length(path)
                print"%s\t%d"%(path[19:],length)

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print USAGE
    else:
        root = sys.argv[1]
        if not root.endswith("/"):
            root += "/"
        process_folder(root)
```

the error seems to be in this line

```
print"%s\t%d"%(path[19:],length)
```

Comment: instead of "seems to be", why not include the text of the traceback?

Comment: do you have a space between print and "%s ?

Comment: Are you trying to run this in Python 3.x?  Your syntax for `print` will only work in Python 2.x.

Comment: nothing just an error message saying "invalid syntax"

Comment: Can you please print your path value. It will easy for making out the error! Cheers

Comment: @Jeremy D yes I do just forgot to put it when i typed the code here

Comment: @iCodez I am running python 3.3.4
any advice for fixing it?

Comment: @user3508496 - See [@Robᵩ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22922936/2555451).  You need to use `print` like a function: `print("%s\t%d"%(path[19:],length))`.

Comment: yes, `print` is function in Python3, so use `print('foo')`...

Comment: @JhonGrant it was just to make sure. I didn't know if you were using Python 3 so I went for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a Python3 interpreter, but not using the required new syntax for `print`:

Try this:

```
print("%s\t%d"%(path[19:],length))
```

and, later:

```
print (USAGE)
```